# Upgrade from 1.6.2 to 1.9.3.10

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm following this:
[How to securely upgrade from 1.6.x to 1.9.3.1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/156795/how-to-securely-upgrade-from-1-6-x-to-1-9-3-1)

Trying to upgrade and old Magento install (1.6.2) to 1.9.3.10 I got:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: [] operator not supported for strings in 
>       D:\laragon31\www\mage19310\app\code\core\Mage\Usa\sql\usa_setup\upgrade-1.6.0.1-1.6.0.2.php:93
>
> ```
> Stack trace: 
> #0 D:\laragon31\www\mage19310\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(624):
> ```
>
> include() 
>       #1 D:\laragon31\www\mage19310\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(437):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb('upgrade',
>   '1.6.0.1', '1.6.0.3') 
>       #2 D:\laragon31\www\mage19310\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(320):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_upgradeResourceDb('1.6.0.1',
>   '1.6.0.3') 
>       #3 D:\laragon31\www\mage19310\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(235):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyUpdates() 
>       #4 D:\laragon31\www\mage19310\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(428):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates() 
>       #5 D:\laragon31\www\mage19310\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(354):
>   Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules() 
>       #6 D:\laragon31\www\mage19310\app\Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->ru in
>   D:\laragon31\www\mage19310\app\code\core\Mage\Usa\sql\usa_setup\upgrade-1.6.0.1-1.6.0.2.php
>   on line 93

What is a correct upgrade path? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culcript was php version. I was using 5.3 and now 5.6

During insteller there wasn't any error shown / displayed, found by trial and error.
It's running fine now.

Comment: Please mark your answer accepted, if it solved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

The second answer on the page will work, although you may need to verify that any plugins or theme enhancements work with 1.9.3.10 or grab the latest 1.9.4 which provides php 7.2 support.

Link to 2nd answer on that page > https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/164735/56995

Also, don't forget to uncompress first (if using compression), delete /var (cache and sessions), and verify file permissions.

Comment: Thank you did, it as that page indicated, same result. Finally found the culprit was php version. Now it's running fine.